# OWLAPI access objectProperty value in a superClass axiom

Tags: semantic-web, ontology, protege, owl-api

I can get access to sueprClass expression by below command.(running OWLAPI v5)
[image]

```
 ont.getSubClassAxiomsForSubClass(cls).forEach(x->x.getSuperClass().getSignature()
    )
```

each loop returns like:

```
[<http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#PizzaBase>, <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#hasBase>]
```

the result is contained of objectProperty value(s) IRI and objectProperty itself IRI.
now i need to catch objectProperty value that is `http://...#PizzaBase`.
 It means get all value in result Set but not the last one that is objectProperty   IRI.

I can transform command to an array `(...getSignature().toArray())` and access its values (except last value that is objectproperty IRI).
 is there any better way or a method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write an `OWLObjectVisitor` that implements the `visit(OWLObjectSomeValuesFrom ce)` and call `x.getSuperClass().accept(visitor);`
Then you can access the object property on the `ce` parameter.

For this case, you could also just cast the result of `x.getSuperClass()` to `OWLObjectSomeValuesFrom`, since you already know where and what type the expression you want to access is. If you needed to do this on a more general way, using visitors is a more flexible approach.

Comment: thanks.and after casting,i could call `.getFiller().signature()` to have a stream containing values

Comment: it is really helped to me.
I am putting my sample code in answer sections please check. it may help some people.

Answer (score 0):

After going though Ignazio's comment, I have implemented the code and it worked for me.
here I am attaching the code , it may be helpful for some people.

we can access from our code like this.

```
OWLOntology ontology =  manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(new File(localFilePath));
ontology.classesInSignature().forEach(c -> {
                ObjectVisitorClass v = new ObjectVisitorClass(c);
                ontology.subClassAxiomsForSubClass(c).forEach(f -> {
                    if(f.getSuperClass() instanceof OWLObjectSomeValuesFrom ||
                    f.getSuperClass() instanceof OWLObjectExactCardinality ||
                    f.getSuperClass() instanceof OWLObjectAllValuesFrom ||
                    f.getSuperClass() instanceof OWLObjectMinCardinality ||
                    f.getSuperClass() instanceof OWLObjectMaxCardinality ||
                    f.getSuperClass() instanceof OWLObjectCardinalityRestriction) {
                        f.getSuperClass().accept(v);
                    }
                });
System.out.println(v.relationToTableMap);
});
```

after that we need to implement OWLObjectVisitor interface and override visit method. I have added only for some as per my need, you can add if you need something else.

```
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.*;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ObjectVisitorClass implements OWLObjectVisitor {

    public OWLClassExpression op;

    public Map<String,String> relationToTableMap = new HashMap<>();
    public ObjectVisitorClass(OWLClassExpression ob){
        this.op = ob;
    }

    public void visit(OWLObjectSomeValuesFrom ce) {
       relationToTableMap.put(ce.getProperty().getNamedProperty().toStringID().split("#")[1], ce.getFiller().asOWLClass().getIRI().getShortForm());
    }

    public void visit(OWLObjectExactCardinality ce){
        relationToTableMap.put(ce.getProperty().getNamedProperty().toStringID().split("#")[1], ce.getFiller().asOWLClass().getIRI().getShortForm());
    }

    public void visit(OWLObjectAllValuesFrom ce){
        relationToTableMap.put(ce.getProperty().getNamedProperty().toStringID().split("#")[1], ce.getFiller().asOWLClass().getIRI().getShortForm());
    }

    public void visit(OWLObjectCardinalityRestriction ce){
        relationToTableMap.put(ce.getProperty().getNamedProperty().toStringID().split("#")[1], ce.getFiller().asOWLClass().getIRI().getShortForm());
      }

    public void visit(OWLObjectMaxCardinality ce){
        relationToTableMap.put(ce.getProperty().getNamedProperty().toStringID().split("#")[1], ce.getFiller().asOWLClass().getIRI().getShortForm());
    }

    public void visit(OWLObjectMinCardinality ce){
        relationToTableMap.put(ce.getProperty().getNamedProperty().toStringID().split("#")[1], ce.getFiller().asOWLClass().getIRI().getShortForm());
    }

}
```